# Does their exist a real continuous function other than $f(x)=0$ such that $f(2x) = -2f(x)$?

Tags: functional-equations

I have a gut feeling it doesn't exist but I'm not sure how to prove/disprove it.
My attempt: Suppose there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\}$ such that $f(a) \neq 0$ . Define $x_n = \frac{a}{2^n}$

$f(x_{n+1}) = \frac{-1}{2} f(x_n)$ and inductively $f(x_n) = (\frac{-1}{2})^n f(a)$

What can I do from here?

Comment: It does exist, e.g. $f(x) = x \sin(\pi \log_2(x))$.

Comment: goodness me^ thanks

Comment: @achillehui Argh, beat me to it :(

Comment: To force the function to be $0$ you need to control the behavior near $0$ a bit.  I think that requiring $f'(0)=0$ should be enough.

Comment: @achillehui - Oh, ok, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Rewriting [achille hui](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59379/achille-hui)'s comment as an answer.)

Yes, there are other functions satisfying that equation. One such function is  $f(x) = x \sin(\pi \log_2(x))$.